# Devise Ruby On Rails Admin to sign out user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying disable a devise user from an admin account.  I want their current session killed and their account marked as disabled.

I figured out how to disable their account so they can't login again, but I don't know how to kill their sessions from outside a devise controller (AdminController

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have instructions on how to do that on the Devise wiki:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in

Basically, create a new column on your database, it can be called `enabled` or `approved`, which is true by default. Then customize the `active_for_authentication?` and `inactive_message` as in the wiki.

The `active_for_authentication?` check is asked before every request, so you will effectively disable the user access on his next request. If you have ajax and javascript, remember to properly handle 401 requests.